# Postorder traversal on a ast.nodevisitor in Python

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, visitor-pattern, postorder

Is it possible to do a postorder traversal on an instance of ast.NodeVisitor in Python just by manipulating the ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit()? I did this:

```
class ExpParser(ast.NodeVisitor):

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        for x in ast.iter_child_nodes(node):
            ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, x)
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)

    def visit_BinOp(self, node):
        print type(node.op).__name__ 

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        print node.id

if __name__ == '__main__':
    node = ast.parse("T1+T2*T3")
    v = ExpParser()
    v.visit(node)
```

this gave me:

```
T1
T2
T3
Mult
Add
```

I want it to give me:

```
T2
T3
Mult
T1
Add
```

How can I do it? please I'm stuck.

Comment: I notice the deprecated `compiler.visitor` package had this facility but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent in the `ast` package.

Answer (score 3):

try something like this

```
import ast

class ExpParser(ast.NodeVisitor):

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        for field, value in reversed(list(ast.iter_fields(node))):
            if isinstance(value, list):
                for item in value:
                    if isinstance(item, ast.AST):
                        self.visit(item)
            elif isinstance(value, ast.AST):
                self.visit(value)

    def visit_BinOp(self, node):
        self.generic_visit(node)
        print type(node.op).__name__ 

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        self.generic_visit(node)
        print node.id

if __name__ == '__main__':
    node = ast.parse("T1+T2*T3")
    v = ExpParser()
    v.visit(node)
```

don't forget to call generic_visit on each visit method, or alternatively reimplement visit method to take care of it automatically.